# Logging Photos from bots dms DJS

Tags: logging, discord.js

I am trying to also log photos and videos as well as messages in bots dms, I did try Discord.MessageAttachment but this doesn't have the right purpose

```
  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(user)
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setColor(ee.color)
    .setDescription(message.content, Discord.MessageAttachment)
    .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon);
    client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(embed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would actually make it like this

For Discord v12

```js
if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(user)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor(ee.color)
        .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)

    // just in case they only send an attachment
    if (message.content) {
        embed.setDescription(message.content)
    }

    // if they add an image/video/file
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
        if (message.attachments.first().contentType.includes('video')) {
            embed.addField('Attached Video', `\u200B`)
            client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
                embed: embed,
                files: [message.attachments.first()]
            })
        } else if (message.attachments.first().contentType.includes('image')) {
            embed.addField('Image Below', `\u200B`)
            embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url)
            client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(embed)
        } else {
            embed.addField('Attached File', `\u200B`)
            client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
                embed: embed,
                files: [message.attachments.first()]
            })
        }
    } else {
        client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
            embed: embed
        })
    }
    let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle('Thank You')
       .setColor(ee.color)
       .setDescription('Your response is being carefully recorded! <:check:947079937372872704>')
       .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon);
     return message.channel.send({
         embed: embed2,
         component: [button60]
     })
}
```

For Discord v13

```js
if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(user)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setColor(ee.color)
        .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)

    // just in case they only send an attachment
    if (message.content) {
        embed.setDescription(message.content)
    }

    // if they add an image/video/file
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
        if (message.attachments.first().contentType.includes('video')) {
            embed.addField('Attached Video', `\u200B`)
            client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
                embeds: [embed],
                files: [message.attachments.first()]
            })
        } else if (message.attachments.first().contentType.includes('image')) {
            embed.addField('Image Below', `\u200B`)
            embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url)
            client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
                embeds: [embed]
            })
        } else {
            embed.addField('Attached File', `\u200B`)
            client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
                embeds: [embed],
                files: [message.attachments.first()]
            })
        }
    } else {
        client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    }
    let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Thank You')
        .setColor(ee.color)
        .setDescription('Your response is being carefully recorded! <:check:947079937372872704>')
        .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon);
    return message.channel.send({
        embeds: [embed2],
        components: [button60]
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks yeah that works too but how would i also log videos

Comment: I have updated my answer to allow for that.

Comment: I updated again to allow for any file attachment.

Comment: Let me know if that solved your issue

Comment: This code is returning a lot of errors when i try to implement 'embed2' into it https://pastebin.com/fWPCAduq in this code

Comment: Updated answer to address this

Comment: https://prnt.sc/dc7kLCVca21a line 63 is what i mean with the errors

Comment: Looks like I missed a couple } in the code I have fixed my answer, please replace the entire code (big section)

Comment: Are you using Discord v12 or v13

Comment: im using discordjs v12

Comment: I haven’t used v12 since v13 came out but I added the code for v12 (haven’t tested)

Comment: the new v12 code posts embed 2 in chat on any message, i dont want to take up too much of your time would i be able to have the original code you sent me just for photos it will work fine :)

Comment: I moved embed to only reply to when the message is sent inside a DM but you can easily remove any section you don’t want or need. On the `if (message.attachments.size > 0) {` section just delete the else or else if section you don’t want or need.

Answer (score 0):

`if(message.attachments.size > 0) embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url)`